# VBA Code error in copying data from multiple WS to consolidated sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to copy the data from multiple sheets to a single sheet. Data range in multiple sheets keep varying, so I will have to copy whatever data is in the WS and paste it to the  consolidated WS. My VBA Code is giving me an error stating, compilation error "Expected Array" at "Last = LastRow(DestSh)". Can someone please help me how to correct this?

```
Sub Consolidatedata()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim shLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Add a new summary worksheet.
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Consolidated"

    ' Fill in the start row.
    StartRow = 2

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            ' Find the last row with data on the summary
            ' and source worksheets.
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            shLast = LastRow(sh)

            ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
            ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.
            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

               ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
               ' worksheet to copy all the data.
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                   MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                   "summary worksheet to place the data."
                   GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                ' This statement copies values and formats.
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    ' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Please post the code of your `LastRow` function. I think that is where the problem is.

Comment: thanks found and fixed

Answer (score 0):

`LastRow` is declared as a `Long` around line 8 in the code supplied. So it just has a numerical value, which defaults to zero.

I'm guessing you may also have a `LastRow` function, probably looking something like this?

```
Function LastRow(sh As WorkSheet) As Long
```

Try removing this line:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
```

Comment: hi,thank you.. yeah i missed the function :(.. i fixed it thanks :)